# Order By Month in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, telerik, telerik-reporting

```
; WITH DS AS
(
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, -25, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(Month, 1, [Date])
    FROM DS
    WHERE Date < GETDATE()-1
)
SELECT
    [EI].[FirstName] + ' ' + [EI].[LastName] AS [EmployeeName], 
    [EI].[DOJ], 
    DATENAME(MONTH, DS.[Date]) AS [Month], 
    ISNULL(HIS.Salary, [EI].Salary) AS Salary
FROM 
    [HRM].[tbl_Designation] [Desig], [HRM].[tbl_Department] [Dpt], [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [EI]
INNER JOIN 
    DS ON [EI].[DOJ] <= DS.[Date]  
LEFT JOIN 
    HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfoHistory as HIS ON HIS.EmpCode = [EI].ID AND HIS.DOJ <= DS.[Date]  
WHERE 
    [Dpt].[ID] = [EI].[DeptCode] 
    AND [Desig].[ID] = [EI].[DesignationCode]
    AND YEAR(DS.[Date]) = '2016'
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(MM, DATENAME(MONTH, DS.[Date]))
OPTION(MaxRecursion 10000)
```

I've created this query in which I am showing the monthly pay of each employee along with there month names. I am not able to sort the month in respective order like Jan, Feb, Mar, ....

What I am getting is something like this:

```
Muhammad Irfan  2012-02-12      May         25000.00
Muhammad Irfan  2012-02-12      April       25000.00
Muhammad Irfan  2012-02-12      January     25000.00
Muhammad Irfan  2012-02-12      March       25000.00 
Muhammad Irfan  2012-02-12      February    25000.00
Muhammad Irfan  2012-02-12      September   25000.00
Muhammad Irfan  2012-02-12      August      25000.00
```

Can anybody help me out how to sort months in proper way ?

Also another this is that `YEAR(DS.[Date]) = '2016'` only accepts integer input but when I pass any date it throws exception. I tried converting date to integer but didn't give any result although records exist. Maybe someone could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Function `year` returns `int` and takes `datetime` as argument...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Can you edit into my query ?

Comment: It should be `year(ds.[date]) = 2016`

Comment: if you want `YEAR(DS.[Date]) = '2016'`, why are you a recursive CTE that generate 25 years of dates ?

Comment: I have a column named dtstart and dtEnd. I want to use these columns like this, `YEAR(DS.[Date]) BETWEEN [Year].[dtStart] AND [Year].[dtEnd]` so that it'll only show records from dates specified in these columns.

Comment: whatever it is, effectively it will only still be only year 2016

Comment: @Squirrel don't follow you. I don't want entire `2016` only. What if the records needs to be extracted between `July 2016` and `June 2017` ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not combine the two styles - pick the proper ANSI/ISO JOIN syntax and use it for **all** your joins!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ORDER BY datepart(MM,DateName(month, DS.[Date]))
```

Just use

```
ORDER BY datepart(MM,DS.[Date])
```

Or

```
ORDER BY  MONTH(DS.[Date])
```

Comment: @Jaysurya it worked, thanks but can you also please see if you can come up with a solution for date part ?

Comment: If you want to order by date, just use ORDER BY DS.[Date]

Comment: Not the Order By part, this one worked fine. I was talking avout this part.
`YEAR(DS.[Date]) = '2016'` 
only accepts integer input but when I pass any date it throws exception. I tried converting date to integer but didn't give any result although records exist.

Comment: add year() on both sides YEAR(DS.[Date]) = YEAR(GETADTE())

Comment: @Jaysurya I added this but it is till giving me whole years records. It seems like it is not checking the fields